# Is there a way to have an editor like nedit with the possibility to scroll horizantally from trackpad?

Tags: touchpad, editors, scrolling

I am looking for an editor like an nedit editor where I could move horizontally with trackpad. For the moment, I can only scroll vertically and it is frustrating to not be able to scroll horizontally.

If anyone could give suggestions of editors that have the both functionalities (vertically and horizontally), it would be fine to tell it.

Comment: Do you like Vim? Gvim has support for that.

Comment: @Quasímodo . Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I already usually vim and I am looking for a complementary editor like nedit but no way to scroll horizontally with trackpad on macOS, it is boring.

Comment: You're welcome. Are there other editors you have looked into or some that you would not like, like Gvim?

Comment: @Quasímodo . I am looking for a similar nedit editor since it is useful to see quickly an array of data, doing a pretty good rendering multiple data.

Comment: maybe ask author of nedit for this function.

Comment: I have got finally the editor `nedit-ng` which allows to get horizontal scrolling on MacOS.

Comment: @furas I have found in [xdvi's manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/xdvi.1.html) that "the X Toolkit routines that implement translations do not support event types of  Btn6Down or  Btn7Down", which are the scroll left and scroll right events. Nedit relies on that subroutines and thus it seems to be trapped in that regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bluefish` editor you can scroll horizontally and vertically using the touchpad.

With `kate` after disabling the *dynamic newline* option.

Also `medit` is another option (not nedit).